# Bash/sed: add extension to end of URL

Tags: bash, sed

I have many files that have a line such as:

```
INPUTS+=('http://domain.ext/XXX/ZZZ/12345')
```

Which I want to modify to:

```
INPUTS+=('http://domain.ext/XXX/ZZZ/12345.ts') // add the ".ts" before parentheses
```

This is the `sed` command I have so far but it doesn't work as expected:

```
find */*.sh -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s|\([0-9]*\)\(\x27\)|\1.ts\2|g"
```

How would I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote: you don't need xargs if your aim is not to get these done in parallel; instead of `-print0`, `-exec sed ...` can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i "s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\(')\)$/\1.ts\2/g"
```

**POSIX BRE details**

- `\([0-9]\{1,\}\)` - Group 1: one or more ASCII digits
- `\(')\)` - Group 2: `')` substring
- `$` - end of string.

The replacement is the contents of Group 1, `.ts` and Group 2 contents.

If you do not have to ensure there are 1+ digits before `'`, and can just add `.ts` before final `')` use

```
sed -i "s/')$|.ts&/"
```

Here, `')` at the end of string is matched and replaced with `.ts` and the match value itself (`&`).

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/RWnbQj):

```
s="INPUTS+=('http://domain.ext/XXX/ZZZ/12345')"
sed "s/')$/.ts&/g" <<< "$s"
# => INPUTS+=('http://domain.ext/XXX/ZZZ/12345.ts')
sed "s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\(')\)$/\1.ts\2/g" <<< "$s"
# => INPUTS+=('http://domain.ext/XXX/ZZZ/12345.ts')
```

Comment: DANGER: (Not @Wiktor's fault) If you are doing this randomly across lots of files with find it might detect other instances of `<digit>')` which have nothing to do with prefix `INPUT+=('https://`. Please consider restricting your sed to match this prefix as well, or you may be very unhappy!

Comment: @GemTaylor :) Right, I wanted to add that to the answer, but since OP inital attempt was based on the digits before final `')` I decided to confine to those requirements. Then, it will look like `sed -i "s/^\(INPUTS+=('.*\)\(')\)$/\1.ts\2/g"` ([demo](https://ideone.com/aYx0UF)).